# develop strange meaning in statement

Tags: grammar

Consider this sentence:

"In this unit, you will read about the amazing physical abilities animals developed to help them survive."

what's the meaning of this phrase: the amazing physical abilities animals developed to ...

if an animal develops their abilities they become more powerful.

so the sentence should be like this ... physical abilities animals developed **them** to help them survive.

so anyone can explain this phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**animals developed to help them survive** is a subordinate clause (but one that is not introduced by *which* or *that*) modifying the noun phrase "the amazing physical abilities".

```
In this unit
   you will read about
         the amazing physical abilities
            (which|that) animals developed to help them survive
```

**them** refers to the animals.

Compare:

> These are the ladders ***fire-fighters use* to help them put out fires**.